# Laravel Ajax shopping cart change the subtotal dynamically when you change the price

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to change the subtotal dynamically when changing the quantity but failing, I am new to Ajax, I cannot seem to figure it out on how to achieve this, will be very grateful if someone helped

Controller:

```php
public function quantity (Request $request)
{
    $carts = Cart::all();
    $carts->quantity = $request->quantity;
    $carts->save();

    return response()->json([
        'quantity' => $carts->quantity,
    ]);
}
```

blade:

html:

```xml
<input class="cart-plus-minus-box qty" type="number" id="qty" name="qty" value="1" >
```

js:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".qty").change(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('checkout.qty') }}", 
            data: {
                'quantity': qty.value
            }, 
            type: "get",
            success: function(result) {
       
            }
        });
    });
});
```

web.php

```php
Route::get('/checkout/qty','CheckoutController@quantity')->name('checkout.qty');
```

carts db:

```php
Schema::create('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: What errors do you got here and what is your expected result ?

Comment: my expected result is when the quantity changes the subtotal changes. and i get this error when i change the qty number. ET http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/qty?quantity=2 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: The problem is you're treating a collection of models as if it was a single model. See the answer below for details.

Comment: Also, your carts table does not have a quantity field according to your migration.

Comment: I have added it in the database.. there is.. but still not working.. can you please tell me what to replace exactly so i test?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code are the lines

```php
// Here, $carts is a collection of models.
$carts = Cart::all();
// Here, you're treating $carts as if it was a single model.
$carts->quantity = $request->quantity;
$carts->save();
```

If you want to update ***all*** Carts, you should use the `update()` method.

```php
Cart::update(['quantity' => $request->quantity]);
```

If you want to constrain that update to a specific subset of your Carts, you can do that by adding the `where()` method.

```php
Cart::where(...)->update(['quantity' => $request->quantity]);
```

For mass updates like this to work, the field `'quantity'` should be in the `$fillable` array in your Card model.

```
class Cart extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'quantity',
    ];
}
```

On the other hand, if you want to update a ***single*** cart, you can use `find()` to narrow it down by its id or `first()` after a set of filters.

```php
$cart = Cart::find(1);

$cart->quantity = $request->quantity;
$cart->save();
```

```php
$cart = Cart::where(...)->first();

$cart->quantity = $request->quantity;
$cart->save();
```

Now if you actually want to **create** a new Cart, you can do it the following way.

```
$cart = new Cart;

$cart->quantity = $request->quantity;
$cart->save();
```

However, this might throw an error because the `user_id` and `product_id` fields cannot be null according to your migration.

Also, according to your migration, your carts table doesn't have a quantity field. Either add it to your existing migration and migrate everything again

```php
class CreateCartsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('quantity')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('carts');
    }
}
```

...or make a new migration specifically to add the column to your table.

```php
class AddQuantityColumnToCartsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('quantity')->after('product_id')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('quantity');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: did not work.. keeps giving  "Creating default object from empty value"

Comment: That means no Cart is returned when you do `Cart::find(id)` or `Cart::where(...)->first()`. If you're actually trying to **create** a new Cart, you should use `$cart = new Cart;` instead.

Comment: No i will not create new cart.. jst change the qty in the card id

Comment: Check if you actually have a Cart in your database if Cart::find(id) is returning null.

Comment: {#1303 ▼
  +"id": 108
  +"user_id": 1
  +"product_id": 6
  +"quantity": 0
  +"created_at": "2020-10-29 16:47:58"
  +"updated_at": "2020-10-29 16:47:58"
}

Comment: Then `Cart::findOrFail(108)->fill(['quantity' => 1])->save();` should also work.

Comment: Oh it worked and did not gave an error, thank you for that. Now how can display, when we change the quantity the subtotal changes aswell? ;/

Comment: There are too many different ways to go about that. Read the documentation and figure out which way works best for your case.